# sizeof(struct) with static const uint8_t

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    static const uint8_t foo = 10;
    uint8_t bar;
}foobartype_t;
```

When I say:

```
uint32_t foobarSize = sizeof(foobartype_t);
```

or

```
foobartype_t foobar;
foobar.bar = 20;
uint32_t foobarSize = sizeof(foobar);
```

it returns 1. Why? Environment is Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit).

Comment: Static members don't contribute to the size of the object. There's just one instance of such member for the whole class, not one embedded into each instance of that class.

Comment: What does it have to do with Qt? By the way, if it is a Qt codebase, please use quint8 or if you only support C++11 and on, use constexpr instead of const.